# AWS Connection traversal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, stun

### Environment

- Machine A is at my house, behind NAT
- Machine B is an EC2 on AWS, and, has a public IP
- Machine C,D,E are EC2 on AWS, have no public IP, BUT, have INet access & access to Macihine B
- machine A originate a webcam streaming video

### Problem at hand

- I would like to connect (non http, persistent connection) to machines C,D,E using TCP/UDP from machine A
- I would like to avoid using AWS DirectConnect/LoadBalancer
- Is there any solution supporting STUN/ICE connections via eg. machine B ( that has a public AWS IP ) ?
- Is there any other way to connect machine A to machines C,D,E w/ or w/o machine B ?
- Is there any way to avoid routing/traversing the data through machine B ?

Comment: Are C, D and E independent machines, or are they acting as web servers? I ask this because you mention a load balancer, which is typically placed in front of 'identical' web servers. What type of 'connection' do you wish to establish -- SSH, or HTTP?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I would like to establish a persistent TCP connection ( video streaming into the cloud ) --- Updated the post to have that reflected

Answer (score 1):

You can **establish a VPN connection** with the VPC.

This can be done via the managed [AWS Site-to-Site VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html) (charges apply), or you can run your own VPC end-point on `Machine B`. Then, from home, you would use a VPN client to connect to `Machine B` and you would then be effectively connected to the VPC.

Alternatively, you could use **port forwarding over SSH** with Machine B acting as a Bastion server.

Or, if you are adventurous, you could use [Port Forwarding Using AWS System Manager Session Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/) to redirect a local port directly to Machines C, D or E. Session Manager uses an Agent to establish a **outbound connection to AWS**, so it doesn't matter that those machines are in a private subnet (as long as they have outbound access to the Internet).

Comment: I would imagine this more of a peer2peer communication using the STUN/ICE/TURN protocols ( bridging routing ), the Q is if there is any existing solution implementing these that I can install on Machine B to support the above mentioned use-case